# Pyscreenshot black screenshots in Fedora/Linux

Tags: python, screenshot, fedora

I am trying to take a screenshot using pyscreenshot in Fedora/Linux

```
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab

# fullscreen
im=ImageGrab.grab()

# to file
im.save('im.png')
```

However the im.png is just a black image.
I have tried to execute the script using sudo but the im.png is still black

Comment: it is wrapper on other programs which list you can see in [documentation](https://pyscreenshot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Maybe you don't have any of these programs.

Comment: I have more than one of these programs

Comment: first check `print( ImageGrab.backends() )`  and then try displayed values in `backend=` like `ImageGrab.grab(backend='scrot')`

Comment: The output of the print is ['wx', 'pygtk', 'pygdk3', 'pyqt', 'pyqt5', 'scrot', 'imagemagick', 'pyside', 'gnome-screenshot']
The only backend that is working with pyscreenshot is the gnome-screenshot but it is making the entire screen white which is really annoying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to furas I found out that the problem is a bug with Gnome Wayland. All the backends but for the gnome-screenshot are not compatible with Wayland, a fast solution to the problem is to boot using Gnome Xorg